# Detecting Differences between two frames opencv python

Tags: python, opencv

I have two frames taken from a web cam. In these frames there is a white area which I need to detect small lines. these lines are propargating by time. this white area is is moving slowly up and down. When a line propagates i need to record the time. I have tried  houges transformation to detect lines but I think comparing two images is a good move. Is it possible to do so? Because frame is moving evrytime slowly.

[Frame 01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGIKT.jpg)
[Frame 02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u45E8.jpg)

As you can see Frame 2 has been moved down a little bit. I want to find the difference between two frames which will not effect this small move

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post your images, that will allow us to help you.

Comment: Hi maybe something like this:
https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/db/d7f/tutorial_js_lucas_kanade.html
Or this:
https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/de/df4/tutorial_js_bg_subtraction.html
Please post images as @Sushi said so we can help!

Comment: I've uploaded images

Comment: Optical flow is probably what you need! Here's the python version of the optical flow tutorial linked above https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/dee/tutorial_optical_flow.html